# How to determine how to compare website navigation text/links to config

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to create a test  using TestCafe/JavaScript that will compare a website's top menu text/links to the expected data stored in a config. I have some experience with TestCafe, but am still learning.

When I set up the function and call it, I enter the function but not the loop within it, as evidenced by the console.log inside of the FOR loop not being printed to the console. I've been debugging this for a while and cannot figure it out.

URL: https://wdwthemeparks.com

Config file (located at ./config/default.json5 in the project)

```
    // Expected Desktop top menu links
    "top_menu_nav": {
        "All": "/all/",
        "News": "/news/",
        "Press Releases": "/press/",
        "Rumors": "/rumors/",
        "About": "/about/",
        "Contact": "/contact/",
        "Refurbishments": "/refurbishments/",
    },
}
```

Selectors and the function in question (located at ./page-objects/header.js in the project)

```
const config = require('../config/config.js');
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

class Header {

    // Top Menu Selectors
    topMenu = Selector('.td-header-top-menu');
    topMenuPageLinksSection = Selector('.td-header-sp-top-menu');
    topMenuSocialIconsSection = Selector('.td-header-sp-top-widget');
    topMenuNavItem = Selector('.top-header-menu').child().find('a').withAttribute('href');


    // Logo
    headerLogo = Selector('.td-header-sp-logo');

    // Nav Menu
    mainNavMenu = Selector('#td-header-menu');

    /////////////////////////
    /////// Functions ///////
    /////////////////////////

    async checkDesktopTopMenuBarTextLinks() {
        console.log('Inside function');
        for (let navText in config.top_menu_nav ) {
            console.log('inside for loop');
            await t.expect(await this.topMenuNavItem.withText(navText).exists).ok(`"${navText}" top navigation menu do not exists.`);
            await t.expect(await this.topMenuNavItem.withText(navText).getAttribute('href')).contains(config.top_menu_nav[navText]);
            }
        }
}

export let header = new Header();
```

Test file (located at ./tests/header.js in the project; other lines in the file commented out just due to wanting to test the function)

```
const config = require('../config/config.js');
import { Selector, t, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
import { header } from '../page-objects/header';

/* TO DO
    1. Check Top Menu item names/links are valid
    2. Check Main Nav item names/links are valid
*/

const siteURL = 'https://wdwthemeparks.com/';  // Set the siteURL into a constant

fixture(`Desktop Header`)
    .page(`${siteURL}`)

test.meta({ desktop: 'true' })('Verify presence and functionaltiy of Header', async t => {

    await header.checkDesktopTopMenuBarTextLinks();

    // // Test the Top Menu area
    // await t
    //  .expect(header.topMenu.visible).ok('Top Menu is NOT visible')
    //  .expect(header.topMenuPageLinksSection.visible).ok('Top Menu Page Links are NOT visible')
    //  .expect(header.topMenuSocialIconsSection.visible).ok('Top Menu Social Icons are NOT visible');

    // // Verify Logo is visible and clicking goes to siteURL
    // await t.expect(header.headerLogo.visible).ok('Logo is NOT visible');
    // await t.click(header.headerLogo)
    // const getLocation = ClientFunction(() => document.location.href);  // Get the URL of the page and set to constant
    // await t.expect(getLocation()).contains(`${siteURL}`);

    // // Verify Main Menu
    // await t.expect(header.mainNavMenu.visible).ok('Main Nav menu is NOT visible');
});
```

So, again, what I want to do is test that the front end shows the text and has the proper href values for each item in the top menu. Those expected values are stored in the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a clear answer to why you are not getting "Inside function" into the console because after a slight simplification on my side it did work. But I have a few recommendations about how to make it a bit more clear + I'll give you a working example.

1. Page Objects should not contain any "checking" logic, that is supposed to be in tests because, well, that's what tests are all about. So `checkDesktopTopMenuBarTextLinks()` should not be in `Header` class. (it will work technically but you'll lose yourself in this structure sooned or later.)
2. `await t.expect(await this.topMenuNavItem.withText(navText).exists)` => why that second await?
3. Try to simplify your selectors as much as possible, e.g. `topMenuNavItem` could be just `Selector('.top-header-menu').find('a');`
4. Json can't contain comments, which actually could be a source of your problems, but I don't know if you just added the comment for your question here. But `config.json` should be just a valid json (you can check it [here](https://jsonlint.com/)). Your example is not a valid json. If I use your config.json with comments, I'll get this error `Unexpected token / in JSON at position 3`.

Having said that, I simplified the example of what you're trying to do:

**Resources/config.json**

```
{
    "top_menu_nav": {
        "All": "/all/",
        "News": "/news/",
        "Press Releases": "/press/",
        "Rumors": "/rumors/",
        "About": "/about/",
        "Contact": "/contact/",
        "Refurbishments": "/refurbishments/"
    }
}
```

**Objects/header.js**

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

class Header {

    constructor() {
        this.topMenuNavItem = Selector('.top-header-menu').find('a');
    }
}

export default new Header();
```

**Tests/menu.js**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import config from '../config';
import Header from '../Objects/header';

const testData = require('../Resources/config.json');

fixture `Check Menu`    
    .page('https://wdwthemeparks.com/');    

test      
    ('Check Menu Items', async t => {       

        for (let navText in testData.top_menu_nav) {
            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(navText).exists).ok();          
        }        
});
```

When I execute this, the test is run successfully:

[image]

Possible further improvements:

- naming conventions: I'd perhaps rename `config.json` to something else. It doesn't seem to me as a real config file since it contains values you're using for checking.
- I'd follow Page Object structure mentioned in the official [documentation here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/page-model.html).
- I'd use a variable instead of a hard-coded URL in `.page('https://wdwthemeparks.com/');`. This URL can go into a real config file.
- I'd keep tests as simple and small as possible. That means checking names of the menu items in one test and checking `href` attributes in another. Perhaps it's not a big deal in this example, but in more complex examples, you'll appreciate having clear and small tests that help you see where the problem is.

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I set everything up just as you did, I get an error:
1) AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

      + expected - actual

      -false
      +undefined

> 13 |            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(navText).exists).ok();

(Shortened due to comment character count limit).

I set up and copied files exactly like you have above.

Also, the comments I had in the json5 file were valid since it was a json5 file. But I changed it to json since I set everything up like you did. Help! Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the code from this answer and confirm that it works as expected. Could you please specify your TestCafe version, the node.js version, command-line arguments, your browser name and version, your platform and its version?

Comment: TestCafe: 1.9.0, Node: 12.18.3, Chrome: 84, Windows 10 (up to date), testcafe chrome ./Tests

Comment: In my case, it's node 14.5.0, TestCafe 1.8.5, Chromium 84, linux, and `$ testcafe chromium Tests/menu.js`

Comment: The test sample from the answer works properly on my side. I've uploaded the sample test and a screencast here: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz2yfmk814809hq/63400883.zip?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz2yfmk814809hq/63400883.zip?dl=0). Please run the following command on your side and record a screencast of your actions: 'testcafe chrome Tests/menu.js -e'.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSkorkin I have this working now. However, I do want to note that it seems to fail as expected when I change a key (great!) but the error message is not descriptive at all. Any way to fix that up so that it can log what the wrong key was? Secondly, when I change a value for a key, the test does not fail, which is concerning. Based on the code, it doesn't look like we are making that check in the test, correct? Could you help me determine the best way of making that check in the test? I will then go and use these examples to complete navigation tests for the main nav.

Comment: Also, thanks @pavelsaman for your help. The above comment is directed to you as well please. Now I just need some help for comparing the URLs on the page to what is in the config. From there, I should be able to go and expand those out to checking the main nav and other areas where needed.

Comment: `the error message is not descriptive at all` => just use an error message in `ok()` function. Just like you used it in your original question. I mean my example is a simplification. `when I change a value for a key, the test does not fail` => my TC is checking link texts, not the url, so it takes only keys from the json object in config. `Could you help me determine the best way of making that check in the test?` => you need to take values from the json object and change agains what you're checking it in the test case. I can do it, but then it's just copy&paste, I'd rather you learn it.

Comment: @pavelsaman I'm running into some trouble here. If I use `// Check Top Menu Nav URLs match config
  for (let navURL in config.topMenuNav) {
   await t.expect(await Header.topMenuNavItem.getAttribute('href')).contains(config.topMenuNav[navURL], `"${navURL}" top menu nav item does NOT match`);
  }` in the test, it errors with `AssertionError: "News" top menu nav item does NOT match: expected 'https://wdwthemeparks.com/all/' to include '/news/'` . I may have changed the names of some of the things in your original suggestions but everything should be largely the same.

Comment: @pavelsaman Just checking in again. Any help with the previous comment?