# How to compare object values in a config to hrefs on a website

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

This is a follow-up to the question I previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400883/how-to-determine-how-to-compare-website-navigation-text-links-to-config/63403450)

In this question, I am trying to test the href values on the website to what is stored in the config file.

URL: https://wdwthemeparks.com

Config file (located at Resources/config.json)

```
{
    "url": "https://wdwthemeparks.com",
    "topMenuNav": {
        "All": "/all/",
        "News": "/news/",
        "Press Releases": "/press/",
        "Rumors": "/rumors/",
        "About": "/about/",
        "Contact": "/contact/",
        "Refurbishments": "/refurbishments/"
    }
}
```

Selectors located at Objects/header.js

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

class Header {

    constructor() {
        this.topMenuNav = Selector('.top-header-menu')
        this.topMenuNavItem = Selector(this.topMenuNav).find('a');
    }
}

export default new Header();
```

Tests located at Tests/topMenu.js

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import Header from '../Objects/header';

const config = require('../Resources/config.json');

fixture `Check Top Menu`
    .page(config.url)
    .beforeEach( async t => {
        await t.maximizeWindow();
    });

test
    .meta({ desktop: 'true'})
    ('Check Top Menu Items', async t => {

        const topMenuNavKeys = Object.keys(config.topMenuNav);
        const topMenuNavValues = Object.values(config.topMenuNav);

        await t.expect(Header.topMenuNav.visible).ok('Top Menu Nav is NOT visible');
        
        for (const key of topMenuNavKeys) {
            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(key).exists).ok(`"${key}" Top Menu Nav key does NOT match config`);
          }

// THE PROBLEM I AM HAVING IS HERE IN THIS PART OF THE CODE
          for (const value of topMenuNavValues) {
            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.getAttribute('href')).contains(value, `"${value}" Top Menu Nav value does NOT match config`);
          }
});
```

I get the following error message from TestCafe:

```
Running tests in:
 - Chrome 85.0.4183.83 / Windows 10

 Check Top Menu
ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }
ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }
 × Check Top Menu Items

   1) AssertionError: "/news/" Top Menu Nav value does NOT match config: expected 'https://wdwthemeparks.com/all/' to include '/news/'

      + expected - actual

      -'https://wdwthemeparks.com/all/'
      +undefined


      Browser: Chrome 85.0.4183.83 / Windows 10

         32 |                   await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(key).exists).ok(`"${key}" Top Menu Nav key does NOT match config`);
         33 |             }
         34 |
         35 |             for (const value of topMenuNavValues) {
         36 |                   console.log(Header.topMenuNavItem.getAttribute('href'));
       > 37 |                   await t.expect(await Header.topMenuNavItem.getAttribute('href')).contains(value, `"${value}" Top Menu Nav value does NOT match config`);
         38 |             }
         39 |});
         40 |

         at <anonymous> (C:\Users\J\Repos\wdwthemeparks-automation\Tests\topMenu.js:37:69)



 1/1 failed (7s)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(Header.topMenuNavItem.getAttribute('href'));`? Does it print the `'/all/'` route or `'/news/'`?

Comment: And why does the diff show "undefined" as the "expected"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry I forgot to post the console.log. I don't really understand what it is telling me but it says:  `ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }
ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }`

I'm also not sure why the "expected" shows "undefined". I'm at a loss totally here. I'm open to a different way of doing this if there is one since this just isn't working. I can't figure this out (whether it is this way or how to do it another way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to get a property or call a method of a selector that matches multiple elements, TestCafe will use the first element from the matched set as a target. Since `withText(itemText)` is missing in the second assertion, your loop always assert the same element.

The diff view for the `expect.contains` assertion has a bug ([DevExpress/testcafe#5473](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5473)), so a clue can be found in the assertion message:

```
AssertionError: ...: expected 'https://wdwthemeparks.com/all/' to include '/news/'
```

Also, I do not recommend using `await` when passing selector properties and method, since it disables [Smart Assertion Query Mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/assert.html#smart-assertion-query-mechanism). It is not a deal breaker in the current scenario, but if you follow this suggestion, you can significantly increase test stability in more complex scenarios.

The following test code seems seems to work fine for me:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(config.topMenuNav)) {
            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(key).exists).ok(`"${key}" Top Menu Nav key does NOT match config`);

            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(key).getAttribute('href')).contains(value, `"${value}" Top Menu Nav value does NOT match config`);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me as well. I appreciate the tips and pointers you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.topMenuNav = Selector('.top-header-menu')
this.topMenuNavItem = Selector(this.topMenuNav).find('a');
```

and your DOM is:

```
<ul id="menu-td-demo-top-menu" class="top-header-menu sf-js-enabled"><li id="menu-item-30278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-first td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-30278"><a href="https://wdwthemeparks.com/all/">All</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23037" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-23037"><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30297" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-30297"><a href="/press/">Press Releases</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23041" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-23041"><a href="/rumors/">Rumors</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10635" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-10635"><a href="https://wdwthemeparks.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-41"><a href="https://wdwthemeparks.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page td-menu-item td-normal-menu menu-item-30288"><a href="https://wdwthemeparks.com/refurbishments/">Refurbishments</a></li>
</ul>
```

so this part `Header.topMenuNavItem.getAttribute('href')` will always give you the first `a` tag, which is:

```
<a href="https://wdwthemeparks.com/all/">All</a>
```

So the first iteration actually passes, but when the loop gets to `/news/` value, it fails.

Basically you're iterating only over your config values, not the tags you find on the site since `topMenuNavItem` returns always the same tag/selector.

So you whole test file could look like:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import Header from '../Objects/header';

const config = require('../Resources/config.json');

fixture `Check Top Menu`
    .page(config.url)
    .beforeEach( async t => {
        await t.maximizeWindow();
    });

test
    .meta({ desktop: 'true'})
    ('Check Top Menu Items', async t => {

        const topMenuNavKeys = Object.keys(config.topMenuNav);

        await t.expect(Header.topMenuNav.visible).ok('Top Menu Nav is NOT visible');
        
        for (const key of topMenuNavKeys) {            
            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(key).exists).ok(`"${key}" Top Menu Nav key does NOT match config`);
            await t.expect(Header.topMenuNavItem.withText(key).getAttribute('href')).contains(config["topMenuNav"][key], `"${config["topMenuNav"][key]}" Top Menu Nav value does NOT match config`);
        }        
});
```

What you should have done to figure this out was:

- simplify the test case to a bare minimum, perhaps getting rid of what doesn't work first and confirming that at least some part works
- using `console.log()` or something to build in visibility
- verifying every line of your test case, you need to know what every line does
- reading the docs

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Regarding your bulleted points of what I should have done, I actually did all of that but as I'm still learning both TestCafe and JS, perhaps there are just things (such as setting the best console logs or finding the best parts of relevant documentation) that I need to get better at. This help and this example (as well as the previous help you've given) are very helpful and will help me learn this complex task!

Comment: @lonepalm: Sure, don't worry, I included them for myself as well, because it's tempting to rush and skip bits and pieces here and there. Sometimes when I'm stuck on something I find it useful to delete the whole piece (test case) and build it again from scratch. It gives me another perspective.